# USB mouse problem in Windows after installing Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows, mouse

Initially I had Windows 7 only and it worked for years without any issue. After installing ubuntu I started having problems with my Windows.

If i boot into Ubuntu, then restart to windows - mouse doesn't work. (keyboard is ps/2 and works fine). I need to restart to Windows again - after it - mouse works.

If i boot Ubuntu again, i need to restart windows at least twice so that  mouse can work again.

Only restart helps. Power Off/Power On makes no sense.

Comment: According to me this has nothing to do with installing Ubuntu and that impacting your mouse in Windows. You have a dual boot system, right? So either you are in Windows or Linux  - not in both of them at the same time. Login into Linux won't cause any issues with your mouse in Windows(unless you are accessing some device driver files related to Windows mouse from Linux). Please check your mouse and may be System's manual.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What could be the problem? How to fix mouse problem?